# Clear all messages from current Terminal session

Tags: macos, terminal

In a Terminal window, if I issues a "clear" command it clears the screen.  But if I scroll up, the messages are still there.

Is there a way to clear call completely?  Currently, I have to close and reopen the Terminal again to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To completely clear the screen in Terminal, so there is no scroll back, you can either use the menu and click **Edit** > **Clear to start** or use the keyboard and press: <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: Clear to start does not work.  But command-k does.